# Pandas average of columns from first non zero values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, average

I have a data about client sales for 12 months.Need to calculate average but with condition - only from the first month when client ordered something (including zero sales after the month client bought something for the first time)

[image]

Using .mean function doesnt give a correct result

Comment: Have you given it a try? Also could you add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) **as code** in your question instead of an image?

Answer (score 1):

Use a mask ([`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with a [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to propagate the booleans to the right) to only keep the values after the first non-zero:

```
df.where(df.ne(0).cummax(axis=1)).mean(axis=1)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 3],  # mean = 2
                   [0, 0, 1, 2],  # mean = 1.5
                   [1, 0, 0, 0]]) # mean = 0.25

df.where(df.ne(0).cummax(axis=1)).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    2.00
1    1.50
2    0.25
dtype: float64
```